# Can I accept payments via email with Authorize.net just like with PayPal?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, authorize.net, payment-processing

As far as I can see this is not the case, however, I thought I would ask on SO to make absolutely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't...

...unless you get *really* creative. You can always have the transaction emailed to you which is then piped to a server side script which parses the email for the transaction information and actually processes it. But it would be hackish and there would be PCI issues to deal with. But it still would be possible.